# Any simple logging library that support .NET Micro Framework 4.2?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-micro-framework

log4net and NLog have support for Compact Framework but not for Micro Framework. Are there any ports of those projects to Micro Framework?

Comment: Did you try to built the [Log4Net sources](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi#Source) agains the Micro Framework yourself? Most certainly you have to remove a lot of features to make it work. A good starting point would be to look how Log4Net [targets the Compact Framework](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html#Assembly_attributes).

Comment: @M.Mimpen I'll try that approach, but I think that it will carry a lot of modifications.